# Cannot use object of type QueryResult as array, Using Salesforce library with CI

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, salesforce

I got an error

> "Cannot use object of type QueryResult as array"

I am simply trying to take state name from the records array but, I only manage to get this error "Cannot use object of type QueryResult as array"

**Model.php**

```
public function getstatename()
{   
$statename = $this->salesforce->query ("SELECT State__c FROM  RI_School_List__c group by State__c");

return $statename;  
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function index() { 
    $data['getstatename'] = $this->model->getstatename();           
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data['getstatename']['records']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anant :) It is working. I just changed `foreach ($statename as $row){ 

    $state_array[] = $row->State__c; 

   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `$statename` is `result-set` object not an array.

So you need to do like below:-

***Model.php:-***

```
public function getstatename(){ 
    $statename = $this->salesforce->query ("SELECT State__c FROM RI_School_List__c group by State__c"); 
    $state_array = array(); // create an array
    foreach ($statename as $row){ 
        $state_array[] = $row->State__c;  // assign value to array
    } 
    return $state_array; // return array
}
```

***Controller.php:-***

```
public function index() { 
    $data['getstatename'] = $this->Footer_model->getstatename();
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($data['getstatename']); // check this and accordingly change you code further 
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solved code Thanks to @Anant

**Model.php**

```
public function getstatename()
{   
  $statename = $this->salesforce->query ("SELECT State__c FROM  RI_School_List__c group by State__c");
  $state_array = array();

  foreach ($statename as $row){ 
    $state_array[] = $row->State__c; 
  }   
  return $state_array; 
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function index() {
$data['getstatename'] = $this->Footer_model->getstatename();            
            $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can do

```
$data['getstatename']->fetchRow();
```

Comment: @RajuKumar  i have added my code as an answer with your cahnge. you can accept it.thanks.